# How do I get the Security Token for PayPal Payments Advanced gateway integration C# ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm kind of a newbie on this paypal advanced stuff. I'm trying to get the Paypal Security Token for PayPal advanced using C# ASP.net. I cannot find any examples that would help me. It seems that this should have been done over and over again. The only example that I find is the php example at Paypal. Here's the page that I'm referencing on paypal.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

Comment: can you consider using this API? https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_creditcard/dotnet?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

Comment: I'm trying to use the hosted paypal pages for this